# Vector Related problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

If $\overrightarrow a ,\overrightarrow b \& \overrightarrow c $ are unit vector such that ${\left| {\overrightarrow a  - \overrightarrow b } \right|^2} + {\left| {\overrightarrow b  - \overrightarrow c } \right|^2} + {\left| {\overrightarrow c  - \overrightarrow a } \right|^2} = 9$.

Then the value $\left| {2\overrightarrow a  + 5\overrightarrow b  + 5\overrightarrow c } \right| = \_\_\_\_\_\_$

My approach is as follow

${\left| {\overrightarrow a  - \overrightarrow b } \right|^2} + {\left| {\overrightarrow b  - \overrightarrow c } \right|^2} + {\left| {\overrightarrow c  - \overrightarrow a } \right|^2} = {\left| {\overrightarrow a } \right|^2} + {\left| {\overrightarrow b } \right|^2} - 2\overrightarrow a .\overrightarrow b  + {\left| {\overrightarrow b } \right|^2} + {\left| {\overrightarrow c } \right|^2} - 2\overrightarrow b .\overrightarrow c  + {\left| {\overrightarrow c } \right|^2} + {\left| {\overrightarrow a } \right|^2} - 2\overrightarrow c .\overrightarrow a  = 9$

$\left( {\overrightarrow a .\overrightarrow b  + \overrightarrow b .\overrightarrow c  + \overrightarrow c .\overrightarrow a } \right) =  - \frac{3}{2}$

How do I proceed from here

Answer (score 2):

For convenience we shall take $a=\vec{a},b=\vec{b},c=\vec{c}$

by your work$$a\cdot b+b\cdot c+c\cdot a+\frac{3}{2}=0$$ $$\implies|a+b+c|^2=0$$ $$|a+b+c|=0$$ $$\implies a+b+c=0$$ $$|2a+5b+5c|=|2a-5a|=3$$